# Insert complex XML into SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

Given this XML:

```
<Documents>
  <Batch BatchID="1" BatchName="Fred Flintstone">
    <DocCollection>
      <Document DocumentID="269" FileName="CoverPageInstructions.xsl">
        <MergeFields>
          <MergeField FieldName="A" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="B" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="C" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="D" Value="" />
        </MergeFields>
      </Document>
      <Document DocumentID="6" FileName="USform8802.pdf">
        <MergeFields>
          <MergeField FieldName="E" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="F" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="G" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="H" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="I" Value="" />
        </MergeFields>
      </Document>
      <Document DocumentID="299" FileName="POASIDE.TIF">
        <MergeFields />
      </Document>
    </DocCollection>
  </Batch>
  <Batch BatchID="2" BatchName="Barney Rubble">
    <DocCollection>
      <Document DocumentID="269" FileName="CoverPageInstructions.xsl">
        <MergeFields>
          <MergeField FieldName="A" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="B" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="C" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="D" Value="" />
        </MergeFields>
      </Document>
      <Document DocumentID="6" FileName="USform8802.pdf">
        <MergeFields>
          <MergeField FieldName="E" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="F" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="G" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="H" Value="" />
          <MergeField FieldName="I" Value="" />
        </MergeFields>
      </Document>
    </DocCollection>
  </Batch>
</Documents>
```

I'm trying to achieve this result:

```
BatchID BatchName DocumentID FieldName
1   Fred Flintstone 269 A
1   Fred Flintstone 269 B
1   Fred Flintstone 269 C
1   Fred Flintstone 269 D
1   Fred Flintstone 6   E
1   Fred Flintstone 6   F
1   Fred Flintstone 6   G
1   Fred Flintstone 6   H
1   Fred Flintstone 6   I
1   Fred Flintstone 299 Null
2   Barney Rubble   269 A
2   Barney Rubble   269 B
2   Barney Rubble   269 C
2   Barney Rubble   269 D
2   Barney Rubble   6   E
2   Barney Rubble   6   F
2   Barney Rubble   6   G
2   Barney Rubble   6   H
2   Barney Rubble   6   I
```

I seems to be getting a Cartesian JOIN with this (each document has the full list of MergeField across all documents:

```
SELECT lvl1.n.value('@BatchID','int'), 
       lvl1.n.value('@BatchName','varchar(50)'), 
       lvl2.n.value('@DocumentID','int'), 
       lvl3.n.value('@FieldName','varchar(50)') 
FROM  @Data.nodes('Documents/*') lvl1(n)
CROSS APPLY lvl1.n.nodes('DocCollection/Document') lvl2(n)
CROSS APPLY lvl1.n.nodes('DocCollection/Document/MergeFields/MergeField') lvl3(n)
```

And am wondering how to get the result I need, with a Null value for the 299 DocumentID in Batch 1 that has no MergeField elements.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Carl

**UPDATE:** Here's how to do the same using OpenXML:

```
 SELECT   
   BatchID,   
   BatchName,   
   DocumentID,   
   FileName,   
   KeyData,   
   FieldName  
   FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '/Documents/Batch/DocCollection/Document/MergeFields/MergeField', 11)  
      WITH (BatchID varchar(100) '../../../../@BatchID',  
            BatchName varchar(100) '../../../../@BatchName',   
            DocumentID varchar(100) '../../@DocumentID',  
            FileName varchar(100) '../../@FileName',   
            KeyData varchar(100) '../../@KeyData',   
            FieldName varchar(100) '@FieldName');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Edit - Sorry I missed the NULL on Fred.  Just changed the Cross Apply
>   to Outer Apply.. The other Cross Apply could be an Outer Apply if desired**

Notice Lvl3

Not clear why you are not creating an alias for each field.  For example, I would expect something like `BatchID = lvl1.n.value('@BatchID','int'),`

```
SELECT lvl1.n.value('@BatchID','int'), 
       lvl1.n.value('@BatchName','varchar(50)'),
       lvl2.n.value('@DocumentID','int'),
       lvl3.n.value('@FieldName','varchar(50)') 
FROM  @Data.nodes('Documents/Batch') lvl1(n)
CROSS APPLY lvl1.n.nodes('DocCollection/Document') lvl2(n)
Outer APPLY lvl2.n.nodes('MergeFields/MergeField') lvl3(n)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thank you (again) John. This is perfect. I can't believe the troubles I've been having with the XML for this project.

Comment: @CarlGanz Happy to help.  I too was a late user of XML.  I watch snugo, he's the xml Ninja